# NOLOCK Hint with varchar(max)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

We have to use `WITH (NOLOCK)` due to few performance issues allowing dirty read.

A few of the tables have columns with a `Text` datatype, and we started getting this error some times:

> A read operation on a large object failed while sending data to the client. A common cause for this is if the application is running in READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level. This connection will be terminated.

This is due to uncommitted data in `text` columns.

Though there are any things to set right, but if we change `Text` to `Varchar(max)` will it allow dirty read in cases of uncommitted data like the one in which it threw error?

Comment: I would guess that snapshot isolation level would fix this error, as read will be made out of snapshot.

Comment: Have you thought on fixing the root problem instead of fixing a symptom? A correct isolation level and indexing architecture should prevent the need of NOLOCK hints.

Comment: Why are you still using the text datatype? It has been deprecated for nearly 15 years now. And NOLOCK is not a magic go faster button. It has some very serious "benefits" that go along with it.